# knockout.js error when binding doesn't exist in foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

http://jsfiddle.net/A7XY3/35/

```
<span data-bind="text: x.ID1"></span> <br />
<span data-bind="text: x.ID2"></span> <br /> 
<span data-bind="text: x.ID3"></span> <br /><br />
<div data-bind="foreach: x.list">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span> -- 
    <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
    <br />
</div>
```

I linked a jsfiddle above that includes the javascript for this issue.

When I am using data-bindings on a javascript object and one doesn't exist, it breaks nicely and just leaves a blank element. However, when using a foreach statement and something doesn't exist, it throws a javascript error and breaks the rest of the knockout bindings on the page.

Error:
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: value is not defined;
Bindings value: text: value

Any help? :(

Comment: You need to use `$data.name` and `$data.value` http://jsfiddle.net/gj43wae2/

Comment: Ahh I tried searching for this answer for a long time and couldn't find it. Thank you!!